Syncing Gradle 5.4.2 with Android Studio 3.5.1 - Sync Failure
I'm currently working with Android Studio 3.5.1 and trying to sync my project using Gradle 5.4.2. However, I'm encountering an error during the sync process. Below is the error message I'm receiving:unable to find valid certification path.
I want to solve this problem iam wationg for your helps
